# Need help regarding scraping facebook comments with BeautifulSoup api

Tags: python, facebook, beautifulsoup, comments

I tried this beautiful soup code to scrape comments from facebook from this link : https://python.gotrained.com/scraping-facebook-posts-comments/ For the code to run apart from the main complete code given on the website, one needs to place username and password on a  json structured credentials file and list of public facebook pages to scrape(example for both is given on the link).  I followed the instructions and ran the code but got the follwong error:

```
INFO:root:[*] Logged in.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vivekrmk/Documents/Github_general/scrape_fb_beautiful_soup/facebook_scrapper_soup.py", line 215, in <module>
    posts_data = crawl_profile(session, base_url, profile_url, 100)
  File "/Users/vivekrmk/Documents/Github_general/scrape_fb_beautiful_soup/facebook_scrapper_soup.py", line 72, in crawl_profile
    show_more_posts_url = profile_bs.find('div', id=posts_id).next_sibling.a['href']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```

When I commented lines 70 to 76 in the main code:

```
    # show_more_posts_url = None
    # if not posts_completed(scraped_posts, post_limit):
    #      show_more_posts_url = profile_bs.find('div', id=posts_id).next_sibling.a['href']
    #      profile_bs = get_bs(session, base_url+show_more_posts_url)
    #      time.sleep(3)
    # else:
    #      break
```

I was able to get the output as a json with values in all the fields(ie post url, post text and media_url) except comments field- it was a blank list. Need help with the above so that I can scrape the comments also. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. Use the API.

Comment: I thought it was possible since I could scrape the post contents, it was only the comments that I could not obtain... but anyways thanks for letting me know @WizKid